# In C#, how to use Span<T> to improve performance with binary data from database?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I store binary data in the database and read it using `SqlDataReader` like this:

```
DataAccess.Person person = new();
person.Photo = (byte[])reader["Photo"];
```

At some point, data from the data access object is copied to a data transfer object. Then business rules will process the binary data which I think will cause another copy of the data. So my binary data is being copied multiple times.

How can I use `Span<T>` or `Memory<T>` to reduce data copying as my data moves from one layer of the application to another layer and then consumed by business rules?

Comment: An array is a reference type, so you wouldn't have multiple copies of the data, unless you're explicitly making them.

Comment: Before you attempt any sort of optimization, you should *set specific performance goals* and *measure your current state*. There's no point in optimizing where either a) you're already meeting your goals or b) where the target of your optimization isn't responsible for the problem.